# My app is incompatible with lg g2 and some other devices

Tags: android, incompatibility, mobile-devices

I had uploaded my app in google playstore. Me and so many of my friends were able to download it and it is working fine in our devices. But one of my friends who has got lg G2 can't open up my app. It is showing "The app is incompatible with your device" in google play.

I am a beginner in android, I don't know what is the problem here. Can anyone help me to find out the real problem ?

The Android Manifest of my app is shown below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.gallery"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.1" >

 <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
     />
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="4"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
     android:allowBackup="true"
      android:largeHeap="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.gallery.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name="com.gallery.Design"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
          <activity 
            android:name="com.gallery.GalleryImg"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            ></activity>
            <activity 
            android:name="com.gallery.FullImage"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            ></activity>

         <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

</application>

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your android manifest file add this
One line solution

```
   <supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="false"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Comment: targeted sdk make that 19 & try again